# BCP utility creates trailing spaces when using FOR XML with TYPE specificed

Tags: sql-server, xml, bcp

I'm trying to export data from SQL server 2014 to an XML file. The file is however created with trailing spaces (65536 columns).

Please consider the following:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(2000)

SET @cmd = 'BCP.EXE "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ''apple'' AS fruit UNION SELECT ''banana'' AS fruit) AS f FOR XML PATH(''''), ROOT(''fruits''), TYPE;" queryout "C:\dev\test.xml" -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -c -CACP -r -t -T'

EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

When I do the same thing without TYPE directive, I don't get the trailing spaces. The query I have needs the TYPE directive specified.

How can the data be exported without the trailing spaces?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. When I remove the TYPE directive my child XML elements go from `<ExampleElement>` to `&lt;ExampleElement&gt;`. If I execute the bcp query the XML doesn't have trailing spaces. However the outputed file does have. Can anyone help us?

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove your last TYPE directive? So instead of having:

`XML PATH(''''), ROOT(''fruits''), TYPE`

you would have

`XML PATH(''''), ROOT(''fruits'')`

It didn't change the XML structure but it did solve the trailing whispaces problem. Give it a try.